# Pulp Scheduling Optimization Problem - multiple supply inputs over time

Tags: python, optimization, linear-programming, pulp

I am currently building a scheduling plan in pulp, however I am struggling to understand how to represent the supply variable for pulp to parse as the data is contained in a multi-index dataframe.

**Problem**
I am trying to minimise any delta so that supply, by plant, by month, matches demand. Note, not all plants product the required product

**Current Supply Data**

[image]

I am aware that pulp accepts dictionaries of variables as inputs, i.e:

```
LpVariable.dicts("Route",(plant, output)
```

however I am unsure of how I can represent **supply** here as:

(month, plant, product, production_output)

Any help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a tuple of month, plant, and product as the key for the variable dictionary and also use it to get the Production Output Mt from the dataframe.

```
import pulp

months = range(1,12)
plants = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E']
products = ['AFS', 'GDF', 'POD', 'PPI']

# set up binary variables for plant-month-product
var_dict = {}
for month in months:
    for plant in plants:
        for product in product:
            combo = (month, plant, product)
            var_name = '_'.join([str(c) for c in combo])
            var_dict[combo] = LpVariable(var_name, cat=LpBinary)

prob = LpProblem('Schedule', LpMinimize)

# objective function
# assume data in df and has index of month, plant, and product
prob += lpSum([var * df.loc[('at', k), 'Production Output (Mt)']
               for k, v in var_dict.items()]

# then add the relevant constraints
# for example, one and only one product per plant per month
# remember that in var_dict the key is a tuple of month, plant, product
# and the value is the binary variable
for month in months:
    for plant in plants:
        prob += lpSum([v for k, v in var_dict.items()
                       if k[0] == month and k[1] == plant]) == 1
```

Comment: Many thanks @Eric Truett - this is what I was looking for. I have another question - would you be happy for me to contact you?

Comment: very interesting. If instead of "having one and only one product per plant per month", we wanted to change the constraint to "a product cannot be present more than one per plant per month", how would that be? I.e. if a product is used for a plant at a specific month, do not use it for the same month in another plant

Answer (score 1):

I think what you want to do is have decision variables which are how much to supply of each *product* in each *month*, at each *plant*. In other words you have the indices: (months, plants, products).

This will of course create a total of `len(months)*len(plants)*len(products)` variables, which in the example is 12*5*4 = 240 variables.

I would handle the case of plants which cannot produce a certain product by setting the capacity for that product from that plant to zero.

```
import pulp

months = range(1,12)
plants = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E']
products = ['AFS', 'GDF', 'POD', 'PPI']

supply = pulp.LpVariable.dicts("supply", (months, plants, products))
print(supply)
```

This will return variables which can be referenced as, for example: `supply[3]['A']['POD']`

Comment: Many thanks for your help! The objective here is to inform the plants what to prioritise, i.e. in some months produce only product 'AFS' and no other, therefore I am trying to understand whether Pulp can interpret a data structure of (months, plants, products, production) i.e. a dictionary of dictionaries?